# Table in iframe renders bigger in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, html-table

Looking for help on a weird situation with an `<iframe>` containing a table.

Live example at http://past.as/stack

In all webkit+Firefox browsers, table is displayed perfectly well.

[image: Desired look - On WebKit and FF]

But on IE7, the table is somehow bigger, both in width and height, with an embossed border surrounding the iframe. There is also spacing between the `<td>` borders.

[image]

On IE8, I still get the weird embossed border, but size is OK. I also loose the gradient background for some reason.

[image: IE 8 good size, loosing gradient]

What am I missing on IE to make it look exactly like the WebKit and Firefox version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think older versions of IE need `frameborder="0"` set for `IFRAME` to get rid of the sunken border. They also add some automatic `cellspacing` to `TABLE`. To tackle this you need to set `TD {border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0px;}`, or set `cellspacing="0"` for the `TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case IE also added a border to all image elements. By removing it and using also Teemu's feedback I solved the issue.